# Issue with displaying spaces in View

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this code in my MVC3 view. but when I browse this it display only W. Why it doesn't display anything after the space? Is there a better way to display this text using `< input>` tag?

```
@var text = "W Z";

<input type=text value=@text >< /input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on @MGA's answer,
consider that the code you have is translated to

`<input type=text value=W Z></input>` before being rendered by your browser. The space after the 'W' would then be a terminating delimiter unless you wrap the value in double quotes (value="@text")

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with two `""` like:

```
var text = "W z";
<input type="text" value="@text" />
```